# Setting the selected index after populating a dropdown list via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am  populating a select tags options via an ajax call and after that  I try to set the selected item in the drop down list using javascript.  But it doesn't seem to be working.

In my Index.cshtml page i have the select tag like this

```
<select id="ddlState">
</select>
```

On the same page I use an ajax call to populate the options list.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/vmsApi",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            $("#ddlState").append('<option value="'+data[i]+'">' + data[i]+ '</option>')
        }
    }
});
```

Then as a test I tried to set the selectedIndex to something greater than 0.. like below:

```
document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex = 2;
```

No matter what value I give for the selected index.. the first item is always selected....

Why is this?

My drop down list does get populated with all the values.  just the selectedIndex wont change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the following does not work?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/vmsApi"
})
.then(
  (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const select = $("#ddlState");
        data.forEach(
          data =>
            select.append(
              '<option value="'+
              data+
              '">'
              + data
              + '</option>'
          )
        );
        select[0].selectedIndex = 2;
    }
)
.then(
  undefined
  ,reject => console.error(reject)
);
```

If this does not work could you please use the dev tools in chrome (F12) in the console tab press control + shift + f and look for `selectedIndex` maybe there is some other code on your page that sets selected index.

To address your comment: the console shows values as they were if it fits in the console.

When you need to expand a value then it shows the value as it is now, not as it was when you console logged it. you can run the following code in devtools console and see for yourself:

```
var i = 0;
var arr = [];
while(++i<300){
  arr.push({value:i});
}
console.log("shows new values when you expand even though the log was before the change:",arr)
console.log("shows old value because no need to expand:",arr[0])
arr.forEach(x => x.value += 10);
console.log("shows new values because it is executed after change:",arr)
```

Comment: Actually I was playing around with it more and i changed my code so that I tried to set the selected index inside my function thats called on ajax call success and it works then.  But if its outside of the ajax call. setting the selected index does not work... is it because the values are not populated yet?..

Comment: @psj01 Correct, the values are not populated yet.  This is because the ajax call is asynchronous.  It is an advanced topic, but here is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @psj01 yes, that is why in my example I use promises. Makes it a little easier to read asynchronous code.

Comment: Its weird though because all the way at the end of my js code i have var z = document.getElementById("ddlState");
        console.log(z); and it prints out the select tag with all the options populated... but if i do document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex = 2; it doesn't work...

Comment: @psj01 The console prints out the object as it is, not as it was.

Comment: Also another thing i noticed is that my console.log(data) inside the ajax call prints out after the console.log(z); which doesn't make sense.. because if that was the case i would only expect to see <select id="ddlSelect"></select> right?

Comment: the console doesn't print out the object with how it is at the time its printed?...

Comment: @psj01 it does make sense, js is executed top to bottom. Then when the ajax call is resolved the resolve handler is called: `$.ajax().then(resolvehandler); this before resolve handler`

Comment: @psj01 I added the demo code in my answer to show that the console shows values as they are, not as they were when you logged them (depending on the need to expand complex values)

Comment: Thanks so much!! That is very confusing though.. I did not know that.. why is it so though.. if its ran line by line.. why wouldn't it print the old values and then the new values..

Comment: If I have the following.. var xx = "original";
   console.log(xx);
   xx="new value";
   console.log(xx);  It will print out 'original' and then 'new value' shouldn't that be the same case..

Comment: @psj01 It has to do with expanding, I added a log in the example that does not need expanding to see values, that log shows the value what it was when you log it. But when expending is needed it will calculate the values when you expand it in the console.

Comment: @psj01 if you were to log the amount of options it would log the amount of options as they are at the time of logging and would be 0: `console.log("amount of options:",$("#ddlState")[0].length)`